# Write down a sentence $\phi$ that for any domain $M$, if $M\models \phi$ then $\vert M\vert <4$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Write down a sentence $\phi$ that for any domain $M$, if $M\models \phi$ then $\vert M\vert <4$

So I want a sentence that says there are less then $4$ elements.

I dont think this sentence works. $\exists y\exists r\exists z\forall x (x=y \vee x=r\vee x=z)$

When I use quantifiers like this $\exists y\exists r\exists z$ does it imply that $r,y,z$ are distinct? Because if it does then I believe my sentence says there are exactly $3$ elements which isn't what I want.

The other sentence I thought of would be $\neg \exists y\exists r\exists z\exists x(x\neq y\wedge x\neq z\wedge x\neq r\wedge y\neq z\wedge y\neq r\wedge z\neq r)$

Which I believe says there aren't 4 distinct elements which should imply there are less then $4$.

Comment: When I use quantifiers like this $\exists y\exists r\exists z$ does it imply that $r,y,z$ are distinct?  no.  Your sentence holds in every nonempty $M$.  You need to say: for all $a,b,c,d,e$ it is not true that they are all different.  Can you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is *almost* correct—it is not implied that variables with different names are distinct.

The reason it is only 'almost' correct is because $M$ might be empty, in which case any sentence of the form $\exists y \cdots$ is false. You need to account for that case as well.

Comment: What about $\exists y\exists r\exists z\forall x (x=y \vee x=r\vee x=z)\vee\neg \exists s(s=s)$? As $\neg \exists s(s=s)$ should only be true for the empty set.

Comment: @AColoredReptile: That works.

Comment: Alright thanks. And can you comment on the second sentence I tried? Does it work?

Comment: @AColoredReptile: Yes, that works too.